# Getting Wifi SSID from ConnectivityManager NetworkCapabilities synchronously

Tags: android, wifi, connectivity, ssid

Currently, the most popular method of getting the SSID of the Wifi network the Android device is connected to is using WifiManager's getConnectionInfo() method. However, that method is deprecated in API level 31. According to the documentation, we're expected to use ConnectivityManager's getNetworkCapabilities() method to get the Wifi info. Unfortunately, the documentation states

> This will remove any location-sensitive data in TransportInfo embedded in NetworkCapabilities#getTransportInfo(). Some transport info instances like WifiInfo contain location-sensitive information. Retrieving this location-sensitive information (subject to the app's location permissions) will be noted by the system. To include any location-sensitive data in TransportInfo, use a NetworkCallback with NetworkCallback#FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO flag.

It seems like the only way now to get the SSID is by registering a NetworkCallback with the FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO flag and waiting until the callback is invoked. This is not a suitable replacement for the old method as the old method was synchronous and could be called on-demand. Is there currently any way to get the Wifi SSID synchronously without using the deprecated getConnectionInfo() method?

Answer (score 3):

I am having issues with this also. Do you need to query this synchronously? Can you not just store the last SSID output from `onCapabilitiesChanged()` in a livedata object, [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-monitor-internet-connection-in-android-using-kotlin-and-livedata-135de9447796) is a really nice resource to help you do that. Unfortunately my code is still giving me null for SSID information using transport info. Can you share your code?

Comment: I guess it's possible for me to refactor my code to be async but that would introduce additional latency and complexity. I need to check the SSID immediately upon app start so I would essentially be registering the listener, waiting until the first response, and then immediately unregistering.

Comment: Regarding getting the SSID, I think you need to pass in FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO to the constructor of the NetworkCallback object when you instantiate it.

Comment: I think this holds true for android version 31 but bricks the code at version 30.

Answer (score 0):

Try the example below, call the method `getWiFiSSID()` inside Thread

```
public static String getWiFiSSID() {
 final NetworkRequest request =
      new NetworkRequest.Builder()
      .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
      .build();
 List<String> ssidList = new ArrayList<>();
 final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
      context.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);
 final NetworkCallback networkCallback = new NetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO) {
      ...
      @Override
      void onAvailable(Network network) {}

      @Override
      void onCapabilitiesChanged(Network network, NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities) {
          WifiInfo wifiInfo = (WifiInfo) networkCapabilities.getTransportInfo();
          ssidList.add(wifiInfo.getSSID());
          connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(this);
      }
      // etc.
 };
 connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback); // For request
 connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, networkCallback); // For listen
 int timer = 5000;
 while (ssidList.size() == 0 && timer >= 0) {
   try {
      Thread.sleep(250);
      timer -= 250;
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      break;
   }
 }
 if(ssidList.size()>0) {
   return ssidList.get(0);
 }else {
   connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
   return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: This solution is working for Android 13. But crashed in Android 8 devices.

Answer (score 0):

In API 31 or above (at time of writing), you need to have these two permissions:

1. `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` *protection*: **dangerous**
2. `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` *protection*: **normal**

Then you can get the SSID synchronously like so:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
      context.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);
Network n = cm.getActiveNetwork();
NetworkCapabilities netCaps = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(n);
WifiInfo info = (WifiInfo) netCaps.getTransportInfo();
String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
```

This is the only way to get the results synchronously. Note, even if you use the async callbacks as suggested by other answers and the official docs, you'll still need the listed permissions to access the SSID.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (am on Android 14). I have all the required permissions in the manifest, I'm also requesting them properly and I have them all granted. Still the synchronous way returns "<unknown ssid>". It looks like the only way is the async option.

Comment: The method "getActiveNetwork" - is depracated, the docs say "This method was deprecated in API level 29. See NetworkInfo."

Comment: That's fine, but it isn't going away any time soon. To be clear, the OP asked for a synchronous way of doing this. Many of the APIs in the Connectivity stack have moved to asynch methods, therefore anyone that wants to rely on synchronous calls will have to use deprecated methods. I'd recommend using the asynch methods, but OP asked for synchronous.